# Create shortcuts "select next" and "select all" for Mac keyboard

Tags: keyboard

In Sublime or [Atom](https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/blob/master/keymaps/find-and-replace.cson#L11) we can "cmd+D" to select next matching character/text. And "cmd+ctrl+G" selects all matching chars/text. How to make such shortcuts in Mac so I could use them everywhere I want - on browsers etc.

For ex. there is a string - "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog". In Sublime I select letter "o" and if I hit cmd+D other letter "o" being selected also, then I can hit Delete and both letters being deleted. I cant think of any reasons for this global OS feature to not be possible. Or are any?

Comment: “cmd+a” usually selects all - at least when I use it in folders or in word docs etc

Comment: @Solar Mike - clarified my question